# Why does multiprocessing raise `AttributeError` for monkey patching?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, monkeypatching

I'm confused about monkey patching in `multiprocessing.Pool`. The patching **worked before pooling**, but the method **lost in the pool**. I know it could be fixed by overriding or modifying `TestClass.test = func` to `TestClass.func = func`

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

def func(self, a):
    print(a)

# monkey patching
TestClass.test = func
print('test monkey')
TestClass().test(True)

pool = Pool()
for i in range(2):
    temp = TestClass()
    print(f"monkey before pool has test [{bool(hasattr(temp, 'test'))}]")
    pool.apply_async(temp.test, args=(i,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The *Traceback* told me `func` lost?

```
❯ python monky_patch_multiprocessing.py
test monkey
True
monkey before pool has test [True]
monkey before pool has test [True]
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Process ForkPoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/seismic/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/seismic/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/seismic/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/seismic/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute 'func'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/seismic/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/seismic/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/seismic/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/seismic/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute 'func'
```

Comment: Multiprocessing never transfers code between processes - it just transfers the *names* of the classes and methods that you refer to.  In this case, the class is named `TestClass`, and the function is named `func`, so it tries to look up `TestClass.func` in the subprocess.  It has absolutely no way of knowing that this function is only accessible as `TestClass.test`.

Comment: Thanks! It is difficult for me to understand the details of `names`. I tried `TestClass.test.__name__ = 'test'` and it worked! Could I know where the related documents are? The document of multiprocessing is hard to find related info.

Comment: I don't know if there *is* a related document for this - stuffing methods into a class after defining it, with a name different than the method's native name, is just too unusual of a thing to do for anyone to have bothered documenting the limitations.

Comment: Thanks for your great help again! I should learn more about basic ideas of python.